# White square after loading in Mozilla

Tags: jquery

I'm running some beta tests in this URL: http://acquasports.esp.br/site/

Whenever I load the main page and the jquery is already loaded (when I click the company logo, per example), the browser Mozilla renders the menu area as a large white square.

What could be causing this?

There are different scripts running in the main page, maybe there is somekind of conflict:

- A toggleFade in the menu
- A horizontal scroll for news

Thanks for the attention,

Leo

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I used some div's instead of ul and il and the problem stopped.